# java running inside docker container cannot see environment variables

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new with Docker. I have a small Java application that I am trying to run inside Docker. I have created a *Dockerfile* to build the image.

My application is reading Environment Variables to know which database to connect to.

When running the command

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 occm -e "MYSQL_USER=user" -e "MYSQL_PASSWORD=password" -e "MYSQL_PORT=3306" -e "MYSQL_HOST=somehost"
```

and then enumerating all the variables using `System.getenv`, I dont see any of them. So I have added to the Docker file

```
ENV MYSQL_HOST=localhost
```

now when I run the container I see this variable, but I see it with the `localhost` value and not `somehost`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is how you are running your docker image.

```
$ docker run --help

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So, you are passing `-e "..." -e "..."` as command and arguments

You need to use `-e` as [OPTIONS].

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 -e "MYSQL_USER=user" -e "MYSQL_PASSWORD=password" -e "MYSQL_PORT=3306" -e "MYSQL_HOST=somehost" occm
```